# Stop Spring Boot from Rolling Log files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I've a simple spring boot application that generates about 10 lines of debug code every 24 hours however it seems that Spring Boot zips & rolls the default log file each day.

Is there any way to instruct Spring within **application.properties** (not via logback-spring.xml) to not not zip/roll the log and simply continue to use writing to the default log file.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.3

Comment: why don't you want to use and configure logback-spring.xml ?

Comment: @sixrandanes - i want to keep the applications' configurations centralised in a single configuration file if possible

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration